# Do I have ROM in my phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, rom

How can I find how much ROM I have? This is my phone, [Samsung Galaxy S LCD I9003](http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-lcd-i9003-midnight-black-mobile-mobcvwavyvzuyh5c). Samsung Galaxy S I9000 has a ROM of 2 GB. What are the uses of ROM? I heard it is used to flash custom kernels. Cant I flash custom kernels in mine as nothing about ROM is mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

Usually, **Read-Only Memory** is called **internal storage**, specifically the system partition on that storage (since other areas are writable by default). The image of the phone's firmware and OS is the **ROM**.  (That's how we do it on this site, anyways).

So your internal storage is 2 GB, and your phone's firmware and OS is installed on that storage space.  You can flash new kernels or entire ROMs (kernel + other firmware + OS) as long as they fit on the internal storage.  Generally, this isn't a problem; you won't find a ROM image for your phone that doesn't actually fit on your phone.